# How to address the LinkGlide "principles shift"?

Tags: discussion

Given the goal of the stack is to make an "universal database", I'm wondering about one point: the arrival of LinkGlide/CUES changes a kind of "rule" in terms of compatibility, which invalidates the "universal character" of many answers. Given we are speaking here about a transmission system that is meant to replace the entry level of Shimano, it's not unreasonable to assume that it will be widespread - I wouldn't ask the question if it were Microshift, for instance (Microshift will probably loose momentum as CUES will generalise).

[This answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/91081/54500) for instance is not universally right if considering the LinkGlide/CUES range.

For reference, what LinkGlide/CUES changes is: there is one chain type for the whole system (an 11-speed one), but the system is offered in 9, 10 or 11 speeds. But the pitch between sprockets remain the same, an 9-speed LG cassette can be considered an 11-speed LG cassette with the larger sprockets removed (the position of the smaller sprockets relative to the center of the bike are the same, the larger sprockets are added close to the center). So all answers that state that a 9-speed cassette must be paired with a 9-speed chain. Same for cable pull and pull-ratios for derailleurs.

Shimano has published a guide to highlight the differences between CUES and other ranges: https://si.shimano.com/en/cues/technical-assets-tips

The least effort solution I'd see would be to add a notice for questions marked with specific tags and older than a given date, would it be possible?

Comment: I've added a tag for CUES and some starter into the precis.   Please feel free to expand or update.   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cues   We probably need a linkglide tag as well - they seem to be strongly correlated.

Comment: Linkglide is the tooth profile, CUES is the entry level family. There’s a Deore/XT line that is Linkglide but not CUES (but that probably follows the design principles - it has been introduced 2 years ago)

Comment: @Criggie Just a note for the guidance: not sure that describing it as "entry level" is the most accurate: officially it's for urban and trekking, and only the U4000 is entry level. From what I could see of the U8000-series components, prices are inline with the other 8000 series (XT Mountain and Trekking, and some Ultegra parts - the comparison is less obvious because brifters are more expensive to start with, and Ultegra is Di2 only now), so it's not exactly "entry level".

Comment: fair enough - feel free to edit.  A lot of that came from a road.cc review article

Comment: @Criggie already done it, it needs to be approved. But I agree, it's a bit of a mess, it looks like a non-performance catch-all product line.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest start with a question on the main site, something like "what is linkglide/cues and how do they differ from existing standards?"

That has the potential to be a [canonical](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical) question and act as a sort-of milestone.  Future questions on the subject could be pointed there, like we do for the tyre-width questions etc.

I've not come across this new ecosystem yet, and it would have easily tripped me up.

---

There is a possibility of adding a "post notice" but the options are limited to:

- Needs citation: This post contains content that needs citations from reputable sources.
- Current event: This post relates to a rapidly changing event.
- Needs detailed answers: This question needs detailed answers, including citations and an explanation of why an answer is correct.

Or mods can Lock a question which means:

> Unless noted, locks disable new interactions (e.g. deletion, editing, answering). Use post locks as a last resort only.

- Content dispute: Lock this post if there are disputes about its content that need to be resolved.
- Comments only: Lock the comments on this post if the discussion is no longer contributing to its improvement. Users will still be able to interact with this post in all other ways.
- Historical significance: Lock this post if it’s off-topic but has historical significance.
- Wiki Answer: Lock this post to encourage users to edit existing answers. Remember to remove unnecessary answers and to mark questions and their answers as Community Wiki posts.

Historical Significance works, but it will label the question as "off topic" which is not true.

---

The final option is editing a short paragraph into each question, but that will definitely push it to the home page.

---

There's always the NULL option of doing nothing, which is perfectly valid too.  Consider how Shimano's Tiagra groupset doesn't mix and match nicely with anything else, and we haven't needed to take any action.

I suspect "replace the entry level of shimano" which I take as replacing Tourney, but BSO's will still come with tourney parts for the next few decades and we'll still get questions on it.

Comment: Erratum: Looks like Tourney will remain, but all series that begin with 2, 3, and 4 + the whole trekking range are meant to be replaced by CUES. The products for flat handle bars have been announced already (and start to be available in online shops and on new bikes), drop bars will apparently follow later.

Comment: Added! https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/91139/what-is-linkglide-cues-and-how-do-they-differ-from-existing-standards